# RabbitMQ and Camel : route interrupted due to "Message dropped on recovery"

Tags: java, rabbitmq, message-queue, apache-camel, spring-rabbit

I'm having a frustrating issue with RabbitMQ and sprimg-amqp. I need to send a message to a queue from an external process (a JUnit class just to test if routing works well). This is my camel-context.xml file:

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route> 
        <from uri="spring-amqp:KipcastDirect:KipcastQueue:KipcastRouting?type=direct&amp;autodelete=true&amp;durable=true" />
        <log message="Message received!!! "/> 
        <to   uri="spring-amqp:KipcastDirect2:TestQueue:KipcastRouting2?type=direct&amp;autodelete=false&amp;durable=true" />
    </route>
</camelContext>

<rabbit:connection-factory id="amqpConnectionFactory" />
<rabbit:template id="amqpTemplate" connection-factory="amqpConnectionFactory" message-converter="messageConverter" exchange="KipcastBean" />
<rabbit:admin connection-factory="amqpConnectionFactory"/>

<bean id="amqpConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
    <property name="host" value="10.211.55.20"/>
    <property name="port" value="5672"/>
    <property name="username" value="guest"/>
    <property name="password" value="guest"/>
    <property name="virtualHost" value="/"/>
</bean>

<bean id="messageConverter" class="amqp.spring.converter.XStreamConverter"/>
```

When I started it using maven camel:run, it works fine. The exchange is available and also queue in RabbitMQ Management. The problem happens when I try to send a message to that Exchange:

```
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
factory.setHost("10.211.55.20");
factory.setPort(5672);
factory.setVirtualHost("/");
factory.setUsername("guest");
factory.setPassword("guest");
Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

channel.exchangeDeclare("KipcastDirect", "direct", 
       true,    /* durable */
       true,    /* autodelete */
       null);   /* */

byte[] messageBodyBytes = "Hello, world!".getBytes();

AMQP.BasicProperties.Builder bob = new AMQP.BasicProperties.Builder();
AMQP.BasicProperties minBasic = bob.build();
minBasic = bob.priority(0).messageId("Test").build(); 
minBasic = bob.priority(0).deliveryMode(1).build(); 

while (true) {

    channel.basicPublish("KipcastDirect", "KipcastRouting", minBasic, messageBodyBytes);
    System.out.println(" [x] Sent ");

}
```

Messages are correctly sent to queue (I can see them on log), but an exception is raised and the route is stopped:

```
[     SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] SpringAMQPConsumer             WARN  Caused by: [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException - Listener threw exception]
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener threw exception
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.wrapToListenerExecutionFailedExceptionIfNeeded(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:590)[spring-rabbit-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:529)[spring-rabbit-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:472)[spring-rabbit-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$001(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:56)[spring-rabbit-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$1.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:103)[spring-rabbit-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor21.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)[:1.6.0_37]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)[:1.6.0_37]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)[spring-aop-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)[spring-aop-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)[spring-aop-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.retry.interceptor.StatefulRetryOperationsInterceptor$MethodInvocationRetryCallback.doWithRetry(StatefulRetryOperationsInterceptor.java:173)[spring-retry-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:239)[spring-retry-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:186)[spring-retry-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.retry.interceptor.StatefulRetryOperationsInterceptor.invoke(StatefulRetryOperationsInterceptor.java:145)[spring-retry-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)[spring-aop-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)[spring-aop-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at $Proxy46.invokeListener(Unknown Source)[:]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:560)[spring-rabbit-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:452)[spring-rabbit-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:436)[spring-rabbit-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:420)[spring-rabbit-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$200(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:56)[spring-rabbit-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:505)[spring-rabbit-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)[:1.6.0_37]
[     SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] erationsInterceptorFactoryBean WARN  Message dropped on recovery: (Body:'Hello, world!'; ID:Test; Content:text/plain; Headers:{}; Exchange:KipcastDirect; RoutingKey:KipcastRouting; Reply:null; DeliveryMode:NON_PERSISTENT; DeliveryTag:2)
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener threw exception
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.wrapToListenerExecutionFailedExceptionIfNeeded(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:590)[spring-rabbit-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:529)[spring-rabbit-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:472)[spring-rabbit-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$001(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:56)[spring-rabbit-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$1.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:103)[spring-rabbit-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.6.0_37]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)[:1.6.0_37]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)[:1.6.0_37]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)[:1.6.0_37]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)[spring-aop-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)[spring-aop-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)[spring-aop-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.retry.interceptor.StatefulRetryOperationsInterceptor$MethodInvocationRetryCallback.doWithRetry(StatefulRetryOperationsInterceptor.java:173)[spring-retry-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:239)[spring-retry-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:186)[spring-retry-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.retry.interceptor.StatefulRetryOperationsInterceptor.invoke(StatefulRetryOperationsInterceptor.java:145)[spring-retry-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)[spring-aop-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)[spring-aop-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at $Proxy46.invokeListener(Unknown Source)[:]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:560)[spring-rabbit-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:452)[spring-rabbit-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:436)[spring-rabbit-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:420)[spring-rabbit-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$200(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:56)[spring-rabbit-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:505)[spring-rabbit-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)[:1.6.0_37]
```

What's wrong with that? What's the reason for which I must generate the Message ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was related to messageConverter bean:

```
<bean id="messageConverter" class="amqp.spring.converter.XStreamConverter"/>
```

has been replaced by

```
<bean id="jsonMessageConverter" class="amqp.spring.converter.XStreamConverter"/>
<bean id="textMessageConverter" class="amqp.spring.converter.StringConverter"/>
<bean id="messageConverter" class="amqp.spring.converter.ContentTypeConverterFactory">
    <property name="converters">
        <map>
            <entry key="application/json" value-ref="jsonMessageConverter"/>
            <entry key="application/xml" value-ref="textMessageConverter"/>
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="fallbackConverter" ref="textMessageConverter"/>
</bean>
```

This fix the problem and the message is correctly routed.